# dc.js incorrect top value with if statement in function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Hopefully I'm not just misunderstanding how dimension creation in dc.js works, apologies in advance if that's the case.

Based on the jsfiddle below, when I create a dimension and exclude some rows based on a column's value, the row is excluded.  However, when I top() that dimension, the value is not only included, but causes an improper sort.

I expect dateDim_no1970 to hold 6 items (confirmed by the dateGroup_no1970 output in the console), but `dateDim_no1970.top(1)[0].realdate` is still returning a value that shouldn't be in the 6 items...

(edit: sorry, I forked from another fiddle for ease of dependencies but didn't link to my fiddle itself, link is correct now).
http://jsfiddle.net/ZHupG/1/

Comment: How are you defining `dateDim_no1970`?

Comment: A filter on a dimension applies to all other dimensions, but not the dimension the filter is defined on. Is that the problem you're running in to?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff sorry, the fiddle link was wrong before, I've updated it now...

Comment: @EthanJewett, I think I actually used the term "filter" incorrectly here.  In the function i'm using to return data to the new dimension, I'm using an if statement to "filter" out a few rows.  Hopefully that clears up what I meant by filter in the post.  Thanks for the suggestion, though! still quite new to dc/d3/crossfilter...

Comment: That's your problem. Your function doesn't return anything if your if statement is false, so you get 'undefined' (the Javascript keyword) values in that dimension. Crossfilter requires that dimension values be naturally orderable, and 'undefined' is not. You should probably just use Crossfilter's dimension.filter function to filter out the records you don't want.